# Prevent absolute positioned nested ul from closing until hover outside

Tags: jquery, css

I have a nav menu and the last `li` contains a nested `ul` to show a dropdown menu. What I would like to do is display that nested menu on hover of the parent li and hide in when you hover away from the menu. The problem I'm facing now is that the menu starts glitching out as soon as you try to mouse into the sub-menu. I'm assuming this is because of the absolute position of the sub-menu. How can I resolve this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('li.has-sub')
  .mouseover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
 })
 .mouseout(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
 });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0 30px;
}
ul.nav {
  border:1px solid black;
}
ul.nav > li {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:50px;
  margin-left:30px;
}
  ul.nav > li:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
  }
  ul.nav > li > ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>Link One</li>
  <li>Link Two</li>
  <li>Link Three</li>
  <li class="has-sub">
    Link Four
    <ul>
      <li>Sub Link One</li>
      <li>Sub Link Two</li>
      <li>Sub Link Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `.stop()` method:

```js
$(function() {
  $('li.has-sub').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().slideDown();
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0 30px;
}

ul.nav {
  border:1px solid black;
}

ul.nav > li {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:50px;
  margin-left:30px;
}

ul.nav > li:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
}

ul.nav > li > ul {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li>Link One</li>
  <li>Link Two</li>
  <li>Link Three</li>
  <li class="has-sub">
    Link Four
    <ul>
      <li>Sub Link One</li>
      <li>Sub Link Two</li>
      <li>Sub Link Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```